# VB app needs Windows TS thin client unique ID

Tags: vb.net, terminal-services, thin-client

I have a custom bar code app running on .Net 2.0 framework and installed on a Windows Terminal Server.  I’m using HP type thin clients and they are pulling their desktop from the TS that has my barcode app installed on it.

For the most part, the barcode app runs with no problem.  The only issue I have, is that my barcode app needs to print labels to a specific printer based on the work center that the thin client is located in.  The barcode app was designed to route the labels based on the device name (Windows name) of the system that the barcode transaction originated from.

I have a full blown Windows XP Pro system also running the barcode app and I have no problem with the label routing because each of those type systems has a unique name that I can use for routing.  Where I’m running into a problem is that the barcode app running from the thin clients, appears (from the barcode app’s point of view) to running from the Terminal Server not the individual thin clients.

Does anyone have any idea how I can pull some type of unique identifier from these thin clients to use within the barcode app to use for routing of the labels?

Answer (score 2):

That is a tricky problem.  If your thin clients have set IP addresses though, I think I have a solution for you.  I found an article that explains how to get the RDP client IP address (not the server's address).  This will have a problem if you are going through a NAT but if you are connecting directly using RDP, it should work:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/857af1fe-75a4-4845-b989-f18636f296c9/

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. I've been searching but really did not find anything similar to what I was facing. I'm not NATing anything ...this app is completely in house and is part of our internal manufacturing process so I think the example you pointed me to may fit nicely.